# ArrayList Double his size each time I come back to the fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, bundle

I'm a new Android Developer and I tried to create some Tourist App"

In my app I have the HomeFragment which have 3 Buttons: 
"Attractions"
"Events" 
"Hotels"

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

private ArrayList<Category> mAttractions= new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Category> mEvents= new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Category> mHotels= new ArrayList<>();


private int mAttractionsBtnId = R.id.attractions_btn;
private int mEventsBtnId = R.id.events_btn;
private int mHotelsBtnId = R.id.hotels_btn;

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public void initCategoriesData() {
    // init attraction array list
    mAttractions.add(new Category("Jaffa Port",5,R.drawable.attractions_jaffa_port));
    mAttractions.add(new Category("Beit Hatfusot",5,R.drawable.attractions_beit_hatfutsot));

    mAttractions.add(new Category("Independence Hall",5,R.drawable.attractions_independence_hall));

    mAttractions.add(new Category("Jaffa Bazar",5,R.drawable.attractions_jaffa_bazar));

    mAttractions.add(new Category("Neve Tzedek St",5,R.drawable.attractions_neve_tzedek));

    mAttractions.add(new Category("Rothschild Boulevard St",5,R.drawable.attractions_rothschild_boulevard));


    // init Events array list
    mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));
    mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));
    mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));
    mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));
    mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));
    mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));
    mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));
    mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));

    // init Hotels array list
    mHotels.add(new Category("hotels",3));
    mHotels.add(new Category("hotels",3));
    mHotels.add(new Category("hotels",3));
    mHotels.add(new Category("hotels",3));
    mHotels.add(new Category("hotels",3));
    mHotels.add(new Category("hotels",3));




}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    // Initiate data for each category
    initCategoriesData();


    // Find Buttons
    Button attractionsBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.attractions_btn);
    Button hotelsBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.hotels_btn);
    Button eventsBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.events_btn);

    // Set buttons OnClickListener
    attractionsBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    hotelsBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    eventsBtn.setOnClickListener(this);


    return view;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Start new Fragment when Button Clicked
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();


    // Pass the right data in the bundle
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.attractions_btn:
            bundle.putSerializable("Data",mAttractions);
            break;

        case R.id.hotels_btn:
            bundle.putSerializable("Data",mHotels);
            break;

        case R.id.events_btn:
            bundle.putSerializable("Data",mEvents);
            break;

    }

    ArrayList<Category> cat = (ArrayList<Category>)bundle.getSerializable("Data");
    int size = cat.size();

    MasterFragment masterFragment = new MasterFragment();
    masterFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, masterFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

}

because all the content is the same ( just the category name is different)
I decided to use MasterFragment in order to no duplicate the code for each Category.

All of the "Data" is created in the HomeFragment, and each time the used click on one of the button's, the app create new MasterFragment and send him the data inside a Bundle in order to let him know which data he needs to show.

This is how the "MasterFragment" looks like:

```
public class MasterFragment extends Fragment {

private ArrayList<Category> mData;

public MasterFragment() {
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle bundle) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, container, false);
    mData = (ArrayList<Category>)getArguments().getSerializable("Data");

    // Create an {@link WordAdapter}, whose data source is a list of {@link Category}s. The
    // adapter knows how to create list items for each item in the list.
    CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getActivity(), mData, R.color.colorAccent);

    // Find the {@link ListView} object in the view hierarchy of the {@link Activity}.
    // There should be a {@link ListView} with the view ID called list, which is declared in the
    // word_list.xml layout file.
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Make the {@link ListView} use the {@link WordAdapter} we created above, so that the
    // {@link ListView} will display list items for each {@link Word} in the list.
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    return rootView;
}
```

}

Everything is work fine, when the user click for example the AttractionButton, the app show the content great(Only the design is bad lol) 
But!!
when I clicked the 'back button' and return to the HomeFragment 
and then click again on the AttractionButton it duplicate the Arraylist
(from 6 items to 12 and so on...)

I fixed the issue by init the ArrayList variables inside the "initCategoriesData" method

**But I still dont understand why the app act the way she did 
I appreciate a good explanation on this it will really help me understand better the way thing works**

Thank in advance, Niv :)

Comment: maybe your **initCategoriesData** called again when go back come. Put Log and check.

Comment: how you back from Master to Home ?

Comment: I just click the "back button"

Answer (score 2):

Because you fragment not destroys and when you come back, your arraylist already has 6 items (Because fragment not recreated). So you add 6 more items too and arraylist size becomes 12. You can make something like this to solve this problem.

```
private ArrayList<Category> mAttractions;
private ArrayList<Category> mEvents;
private ArrayList<Category> mHotels;

public void initCategoriesData() {

//initialize array list here

mAttractions= new ArrayList<>()
mEvents= new ArrayList<>();
mHotels= new ArrayList<>();

// init attraction array list
mAttractions.add(new Category("Jaffa Port",5,R.drawable.attractions_jaffa_port));
mAttractions.add(new Category("Beit Hatfusot",5,R.drawable.attractions_beit_hatfutsot));

mAttractions.add(new Category("Independence Hall",5,R.drawable.attractions_independence_hall));

mAttractions.add(new Category("Jaffa Bazar",5,R.drawable.attractions_jaffa_bazar));

mAttractions.add(new Category("Neve Tzedek St",5,R.drawable.attractions_neve_tzedek));

mAttractions.add(new Category("Rothschild Boulevard St",5,R.drawable.attractions_rothschild_boulevard));


// init Events array list
mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));
mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));
mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));
mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));
mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));
mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));
mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));
mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));

// init Hotels array list
mHotels.add(new Category("hotels",3));
mHotels.add(new Category("hotels",3));
mHotels.add(new Category("hotels",3));
mHotels.add(new Category("hotels",3));
mHotels.add(new Category("hotels",3));
mHotels.add(new Category("hotels",3));
```

}

Hope it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

See the image above from the [Android developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Creating), the `onCreateView()` is called when the fragment was uncovered by user's pressing back button. And subsequently does `initCategoriesData()`.

**The fragment returns from the back stack to the layout, and then `onCreateView()` and `initCategoriesData()` are called.**

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you return to the HomeFragment the `OnCreateView` method is called and the `initCategoriesData()` aswell, becouse the view is being recreated. Try putting the function in some other place, `onCreate()` should be fine

Answer (score 0):

//Try this.
While you are not clearing your lists before adding data into it.
Clear your list as i have updated this in your code.

```
   public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

        private ArrayList<Category> mAttractions= new ArrayList<>();
        private ArrayList<Category> mEvents= new ArrayList<>();
        private ArrayList<Category> mHotels= new ArrayList<>();


        private int mAttractionsBtnId = R.id.attractions_btn;
        private int mEventsBtnId = R.id.events_btn;
        private int mHotelsBtnId = R.id.hotels_btn;

        public HomeFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        public void initCategoriesData() {
            // init attraction array list
       mAttractions.clear();
       mEvents.clear();
       mHotels.clear();
            mAttractions.add(new Category("Jaffa Port",5,R.drawable.attractions_jaffa_port));
            mAttractions.add(new Category("Beit Hatfusot",5,R.drawable.attractions_beit_hatfutsot));

            mAttractions.add(new Category("Independence Hall",5,R.drawable.attractions_independence_hall));

            mAttractions.add(new Category("Jaffa Bazar",5,R.drawable.attractions_jaffa_bazar));

            mAttractions.add(new Category("Neve Tzedek St",5,R.drawable.attractions_neve_tzedek));

            mAttractions.add(new Category("Rothschild Boulevard St",5,R.drawable.attractions_rothschild_boulevard));


            // init Events array list
            mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));
            mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));
            mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));
            mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));
            mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));
            mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));
            mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));
            mEvents.add(new Category("cacdas",3));

            // init Hotels array list
            mHotels.add(new Category("hotels",3));
            mHotels.add(new Category("hotels",3));
            mHotels.add(new Category("hotels",3));
            mHotels.add(new Category("hotels",3));
            mHotels.add(new Category("hotels",3));
            mHotels.add(new Category("hotels",3));




        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

            // Initiate data for each category
            initCategoriesData();


            // Find Buttons
            Button attractionsBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.attractions_btn);
            Button hotelsBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.hotels_btn);
            Button eventsBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.events_btn);

            // Set buttons OnClickListener
            attractionsBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
            hotelsBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
            eventsBtn.setOnClickListener(this);


            return view;
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Start new Fragment when Button Clicked
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null);

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();


            // Pass the right data in the bundle
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.attractions_btn:
                    bundle.putSerializable("Data",mAttractions);
                    break;

                case R.id.hotels_btn:
                    bundle.putSerializable("Data",mHotels);
                    break;

                case R.id.events_btn:
                    bundle.putSerializable("Data",mEvents);
                    break;

            }

            ArrayList<Category> cat = (ArrayList<Category>)bundle.getSerializable("Data");
            int size = cat.size();

            MasterFragment masterFragment = new MasterFragment();
            masterFragment.setArguments(bundle);

            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, masterFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
```

Comment: Clear list, before adding data into list.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `fragmentTransaction.replace()`, `HomeFragment.onCreate()` and `HomeFragment.onCreateView()` will be called everytime you go back to it. So `initCategoriesData()` will also be called. You can either clear and init all data from scratch everytime or use `fragmentTransaction.add()` instead of `fragmentTransaction.replace()` to avoid this problem.

`fragmentTransaction.replace()` swaps out your current fragment. It no longer attached to the activity but the `Fragment` object is still alive and all data stored in variables are still there. When you bring it back to the activity, it called `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()` to recreate its view again.
These actions happen when you `replace()` and go back:

1. `HomeFragment` goes away
2. `MasterFragment` comes
3. `MasterFragment` goes away
4. `HomeFragment` comes back, trigger `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()`

`fragmentTransaction.add()` behaves like adding another `Fragment` on top of your current `Fragment`, without moving it away. When you go back, it just reveals the original `Fragment` which have been sitting there without any actions. These actions happen when you `add()` and go back

1. `MasterFragment` comes, covering `HomeFragment`
2. `MasterFragment` goes away, revealing `HomeFragment`

`HomeFragment` is basically untouched this time so nothing is triggered on it.

Comment: Thats a great answer, thanks what do you suggest using in this case?

Comment: I would suggest using `fragmentTransaction.add()`